# Storing Credit Card details securely in Database

Tags: mysql, security, encryption

The company I work for has recently started advertising products in a newspaper. The newspaper advertises it with a link to their own website, where the customer enters their details (billing/shipping address, product, card details).

The newspapers website doesn't charge the card, instead all of the order information is stored in an encrypted XML file which is then sent to us. We then have to manually enter the details into our card machine.

I have written a quick script which converts these XML files into a CSV file which can then be imported into a MySQL database, so that we can keep track of all orders easily.

What I want to know is how can we securely store the card number, security code etc. So that if anyone ever gained access to the database they wouldn't be able to steal the details, but we can still view them to enter into our card machine. Is this possible?

Comment: This is too broad. Also, you are not permitted to store security code data in your database according to PCI standards.

Comment: You need to read about PCI compliance.  Pretty sure that's illegal in some countries.

Comment: @JohnConde I wasn't aware of that, I will take it into consideration.

Comment: @JohnConde You should be able to store encrypted CC numbers meeting PCI standards but not Track 2 data.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should not save the CC numbers. If you do save the data it weill have to be encrypted and meet PCI standards, look at the Point-to-Point and DSS documents. Better yet hire a PCI auditor to help you.

You need to talk to the service you are using, you may be subject to PCI audits.

See [PCI](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org).